# Paypal Refund NVP API : You do not have permission to refund this transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

i Am using Paypal NVP Refund Api For Refund Paypal Transaction.
All Things are ok but when i try to rung api, it gives me below Response.

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2017-07-17T13:58:24Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 51.0
    [BUILD] => 36458220
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10007
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Permission denied
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You do not have permission to refund this transaction
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

is that some process i miss to call.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving permission same issue exists.
Then I found I missed an argument..

I'm sending this request.

```
$nvpreq = array(
    'USER' => '',
    'PWD' => '',
    'SIGNATURE' => '',
    'METHOD'=> 'RefundTransaction',
    'VERSION' => urlencode('94'),
    'TRANSACTIONID' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'REFUNDTYPE' => 'Partial',
    'AMT' => '0.01',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD');
```

I forgot to add `'SUBJECT' => 'reiceversemail@gmail.com',`.
Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the some causes of this error.

1. You used the wrong transaction ID.
2. You're trying to make the call for a third party and have the wrong
   email address in the subject.
3. The subject account hasn't given you permission to make the
   third-party call.

Here is link you can check this. [Why did I get API error code 10007?](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1124&actp=RSS)

Comment: Transaction id is right. if i use wrong transaction id . is gives response that `invalid transaction id`.@hamza zafeer

Comment: You are using your own Paypal account?

Comment: @Rizwan Have permission to make a refund on behalf of the receiver, unless you are also the receiver; in other words, each receiver whose account is the source of the refund must have granted you third-party access permission to call the Refund API operation...Checkout this. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/

Comment: Yes I m using my own PayPal account.@Hamza zafeer

Comment: Thankx @hamza zafeer .

Comment: This is happening to me because by mistake I accepted payment with my personal Paypal account and not the Business one. Unfortunately not sure how to deal with this in term of old payments.