# paypal transaction id from express checkout

Tags: php, laravel-5, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am unable to get the transactions id from paypal ExpressCheckout method.

```
 $provider = new ExpressCheckout;
 $response = $provider->getExpressCheckoutDetails($request->token);
 echo "<pre>";print_r($response);
Array
(
  [TOKEN] => EC-79454119W8713794B
  [BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS] => 1
  [CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated
  [TIMESTAMP] => 2021-11-01T04:14:23Z
  [CORRELATIONID] => f00ab9c2819b4
  [ACK] => Success
  [VERSION] => 123
  [BUILD] => 55938276
  [EMAIL] => john@abc.com
  [PAYERID] => 238MG2US77AQY
  [PAYERSTATUS] => unverified
  [FIRSTNAME] => john
  [LASTNAME] => doe
  [COUNTRYCODE] => US
  [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
  [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
  [AMT] => 24.99
  [ITEMAMT] => 24.99
  [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
  [HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
  [TAXAMT] => 0.00
  [DESC] => Order #61 Invoice
  [INVNUM] => 61
  [NOTIFYURL] => https://example.com/ipn/notify
  [INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
  [SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
  [INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
  [L_NAME0] => Monthly Unlimited
  [L_QTY0] => 1
  [L_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
  [L_AMT0] => 24.99
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 24.99
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 24.99
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC] => Order #61 Invoice
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM] => 61
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL] => https://example.com/ipn/notify
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => abc@gmail.com
  [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
  [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Monthly Unlimited
  [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
  [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
  [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 24.99
  [PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
)
```

I need transaction id for making refund. that's why I need transaction id.
This is the function I am trying for refund

```
$response = $provider->refundTransaction($transactionid);
```

Answer (score 0):

- using getExpressCheckout - wont give you the transaction ID
- you will be getting transaction id from the doExpressCheckout API in
  the response.
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/do-express-checkout-payment-nvp/#doexpresscheckoutpayment-request-message
- Then persist / store this transaction id and later you can do the
  refund process.

  - If you didnot store the transaction id, then using Invoice Number you
    can consume the api Transaction Search API
    https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/transaction-search-nvp/#transactionsearch-response-message. It has multiple params (search option), so you will get the
    transaction id.
- But PayPal recommends to go with Option 1 . Store the transacton id and go for further refund process (instead of search api)

Comment: i am getting transaction id from this doExpressCheckoutPayment. When i am trying to pass this transaction on refund function it give me a message "You do not have permission to refund this transaction"

Comment: check you have the permission and you are passing the subjectt. Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146366/paypal-refund-nvp-api-you-do-not-have-permission-to-refund-this-transaction

Answer (score 0):

You will get it after you perform the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call. Before that, I don't think you can get transaction ID. YOu will get response like:
doExpressCheckoutPayment:

```
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-2FR88291S31672645
    [SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-02-24T10:26:08Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => a95c7a9bb64b3
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 84
    [BUILD] => 2571254
    [INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
    [SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 2RN165632T770592L
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME] => 2012-02-24T10:26:06Z
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT] => 10.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => authorization
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE] => None
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Eligible
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => WLC8CZSP2C5L8
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Success
)
```